# Dual battery switching to load

Tags: batteries

I have one circuit which has a Li-ion rechargeable battery and a non-rechargeable Li-ion battery. My circuit should work on a rechargeable battery in normal operation but when my rechargeable battery is in low-battery mode my system should work on a non-rechargeable battery.

For this reason I have put in two Schottky diodes and the circuit is working fine but I also want to give indication to my micro-controller that the system is working on a non-rechargeable battery. In this case what could be the circuit and what would be its flow?

Comment: I would directly monitor the rechargeable battery voltage with an ADC on the micro controller. Likewise, I would probably let the micro-controller be responsible for enabling the non-rechargeable battery with a PMOS load switch.

Answer (score 1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIXAib.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Your configuration.*

Unfortunately you will not get a clean switchover from one battery to the other. As the battery with the higher voltage discharges and gets within the Schottky voltage drop of the other battery the other battery will start to contribute current in a very "soft" transition or "merge".

[image]

*Figure 2. Battery currents as a function of battery voltages.*

Figure 2 shows a nice transition but that's only because the simulation has kept V<sub>BAT2</sub> a constant. In practice both batteries will power the load and will decrease together at the same voltage and rate of droop.

Summary:

> My circuit should work on rechargeable battery on normal operation but when my rechargeable battery is in low battery mode my system should work on non-rechargeable battery.

- Your circuit doesn't work like that. It will run on the higher voltage battery until it discharges enough that **both** batteries will supply power from then on.
- It will not be simple to add an indicator. Your best chance would be to add a comparator monitoring the voltage across D2 to indicate that it is now supplying significant current.

Answer (score 0):

The schottkies drop (even <0.4v) is too much waist in low voltage battery design. Use BJTs or Pmos rather. To switch between batteries use SR flop initially sets to reset state so Q_neg will connect Rechargeable battery first. After Rechargeable battery voltage falls below 3V (set by Ref_3V made with TL431 ref.) the comparator switches the SR flop to Set state so Q output connects Nonrechargeable bat. and disconnect rechargeable bat. immediatelly.

For SRflop, comparator and 3V reference supply use Nonrech. battery - it will not drain too much. I expect you dont want run on Nonrech too long so you can be sure you will have enough voltage to supply this logic all the time.

If you have microcontroller in your app. you can do this logic with its internal harware (except transistors).

For indication about what battery is currently connected you can use Q and Q_neg output signals from SR flop.

[image]